# Rails Two Views With One Controller#Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a rails association "user has many follows" currently have lists of user's followers and followings. I want to have 2 links on`users#show` to display lists of followers and followings. I know I can render two different views in my `follows#index` using `if else` statement but I'm not sure how to go about it. My initial thought was to have rails check which link was clicked (either 'Followers' or 'Followings') but I couldn't find an exact answer. I also thought of creating two different tables (Followers, Followings) but adding 2 same values for 1 action seemed redundant and waste of space.

Here is my FollowsController:

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @follows = Follow.all
    render :index
  end

  def create
    @follow = Follow.create(follow_params)
    redirect_to user_url(@follow.user_id)
  end

  def destroy
    @follow = Follow.find(params[:id])
    @follower_id = @follow.user_id
    @follow.destroy!
    redirect_to user_url(@follower_id)
  end

  private

  def follow_params
    params.require(:follow).permit(:follower_id, :user_id)
  end

end
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: I don't get your need exactly but I guess you can send param through link to know which one is clicked.

Comment: what do you think about my solution?

Comment: That's what I was suggesting. You can filter from Follow according to the param. No need of two tables.

Comment: perfect. thanks for the quick review

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
def index
  @follows = Follow.all    
  if @follows.present?
    render 'show_with_followers'
  else
    render 'show_without_followings'
  end
end
```

**views**

```
app/views/follows/_show_with_followers.html.erb
app/views/follows/_show_without_followings.html.erb
```

Comment: Is only one example, the main problem is how to render two views using render.

Comment: yeah, in this case; you have the reason. I only wrote without think in that hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer I found so far. I will be using in my view

```
<%= link_to 'Followers', follows_path(:follows => 'followers') %>
<%= link_to 'Followings', follows_path(:follows => 'followings') %>
```

and use

```
def index
    if params["follows"] == 'followers'
      #render followers
    else
      #render followings
    end
  end
end
```